# Why does javascript array with very high index numbers lead to crash / slow down / trouble?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically the code that broke my node js express server was this:

```
resultArr = [];
resultArr["test"] = [];
resultArr["test"][2015073012] = someObject;
```

when I changed this to this, it ran without problems

```
resultArr = [];
resultArr["test"] = {};
resultArr["test"][2015073012] = someObject;
```

I did work like this in a loop.

Why did it break my app?

Comment: It depends on the specific JS implementation (V8 in this case). I am surprised it caused it to 'crash' as I would expect it to have been built as - or converted to - a sparse-array implementation (being that it is over ~105k indexes). If it does cause it to 'crash' then my first hunch is it is still trying to use the dense-array implementation .. or that something else is amiss.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  What you have there works just fine.

Comment: According to ES5, the maximum length of an array is 2^32-1,but it will be sluggish if the the array have many element, until out of memery.

Comment: @kenticny That is not entirely true. Modern JS engines have several different array implementations - most notably: a 'dense' backed by a continuous allocation, and a 'sparse' more like a normal object - and can switch between them; and the behavior and conditions are entirely implementation-dependent. Why V8 is failing to do so in this case is the question.. I would not be surprised if there is a bug report somewhere.

Comment: Related to the *different* backing implementations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961838/working-with-arrays-in-v8-performance-issue , http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/

Comment: @user2864740 - Thanks for the interesting and informative comments, both above and the (now deleted) comments on my answer that kept me on my toes while I was writing it. :-) You made a great contribution to this discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you found, you shouldn't be using arrays for this, you should be using objects. But you should go a step further and use an object for the top level as well. And since your `2015073012` value will be used as a string, it's a good practice to make it one from the start:

```
var results = {};
results.test = {};
results.test['2015073012'] = someObject;
```

or:

```
var results = {};
results['test'] = {};
results['test']['2015073012'] = someObject;
```

Now you won't have any problem in any JavaScript engine.

(As an aside, I changed the name from `resultArr` to `results` so the name doesn't make it sound like it's an array.)

JavaScript arrays are for cases where you have sequential entries like `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]`, etc. When you have arbitrary strings or arbitrarily large numbers for keys, do not use an array, use an object.

Don't be confused by other languages such as PHP that have a single `array` type which serves both as a sequential `0,1,2,3,...` array and as a dictionary of key-value pairs. JavaScript has both arrays and objects: use arrays for the sequential case and objects for the key-value case.

Back to your question, why *did* this code break:

```
resultArr = [];
resultArr["test"] = [];
resultArr["test"][2015073012] = someObject;
```

One possible explanation is that the JavaScript engine is doing exactly what you told it to do when you assign a value to the `[2015073012]` array index: it creates an array with **2,015,073,013** entries (one more than the value you gave, because array indexes start at 0). That is over *two billion* entries in your array! You can probably see how that would cause a problem - and it certainly isn't what you intended.

Other engines may realize that this is a ridiculously large number and treat it as a string instead of a number, as if you'd used an object instead of an array in the first place. (A JavaScript array is *also* an object and can have key-value pairs as well as numeric indices.)

In fact, I crossed my fingers and tried this in the JavaScript console in the latest version of Chrome, and it worked with no problem:

```
a = [];
a[2015073012] = {};
```

But you weren't as lucky. In any case, you should always use objects instead of arrays for this kind of use, to insure that they are treated as key-value pairs instead of creating enormous arrays with mostly-empty elements.